# Microsoft AJAX Toolkit Calendar Control: how do you programmatically close using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using classic Web Forms and successfully employing the Microsoft AJAX Toolkit Calendar control. However, we have situations where the calendar is "stuck" open, particuarly while we are doing a "Please Wait" on the Ajax Update Panel. We are disabling the screen using Javascript, displaying a "Please Wait" message but the Calendar control can be stuck open during these situtations.

I need the Javascript API call to programatically close this control from Javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit Calendar has a [`hide()` method](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/how%20to%20use%20the%20calendar%20control.ashx#Methods_2) and an [`isOpen` property](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/how%20to%20use%20the%20calendar%20control.ashx#Properties_3).